# Error occurred in executing Table type parameter

Tags: sql-server, biztalk, biztalk-2013

I am trying to insert data into table using BizTalk with below code. But I am facing error as "Procedure or function Emp_Details has too many arguments specified."

Could someone help me out to solve the same?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Emp_Details]

                (@InsertDetails InsertDetailsType readonly)
    AS
    Begin 

    Truncate table [dbo].[Emp_Details]

          INSERT INTO [dbo].[Emp_Details]
               (
                [NAME],
                [DESCRIPTION],
                [EMPID]

            )
        select 

                [NAME],
                [DESCRIPTION],
                [EMPID]
    from @InsertDetails;


    Begin
    if exists(select 1 from [dbo].[Emp_Details]where NAME='Raul')

    Delete from [Emp_Details]where NAME='Raul'

    End 

    end
```

Comment: where you declare this table type @InsertAircraft

Comment: Edited..now check the code

Comment: In the first statement your truncating Emp_Details table then why your going for if exists condition

Comment: It's because... While inserting the file could contain a row which is not required into table... So one all rows are inserted... It would get deleted

Comment: Can you post the BizTalk Schema you are using to call the stored procedure?   I suspect that you will not get BizTalk to work with a custom database type and you will have to pass `@NAME`, `@DESCRIPTION`  & `@EMPID` as separate parameters.  In fact that is possibly what it is doing, and hence you are getting the error.

Answer (score -1):

Reposting the same sample code used previously for reference.

```
USE <Database>
GO

/* This is a template table */
CREATE TYPE Emp_Details AS TABLE   
( [Name]        VARCHAR(100)  
, [Description] VARCHAR(100) 
, [Address]     VARCHAR(100));  
GO

/* The following is your Table Emp_Details which you must be having already*/
CREATE TABLE Emp_Details
( [Name]        VARCHAR(100)  
, [Description] VARCHAR(100) 
, [Address]     VARCHAR(100));  
GO 

/* Consider this as your Input Data i.e CSV file or Excel (Note: I have created a table for sample)*/
CREATE TABLE Emp_Details1
( [Name]        VARCHAR(100)  
, [Description] VARCHAR(100) 
, [Address]     VARCHAR(100));  
GO 


INSERT INTO Emp_Details1 VALUES ('John','Test','123')
INSERT INTO Emp_Details1 VALUES ('John1','Test1','1234')
INSERT INTO Emp_Details1 VALUES ('John2','Test2','1235')
GO

SELECT * FROM Emp_Details

/* Declare a variable that references the type. So when you reference a `TYPE` it takes the table template which we created previously*/  
DECLARE @Emp AS Emp_Details;  

/* Add data to the table variable. In your case push the data that you get into the @Emp */  
INSERT INTO @Emp ([Name], [Description], [Address])  
    SELECT [Name], [Description], [Address]
    FROM Emp_Details1;  

/* Pass the table variable data to a stored procedure. */  
EXEC [dbo].[Insert_Deatils]  @Emp;  
GO 

SELECT * FROM Emp_Details
```

Comment: i didnt understood this

Comment: @Raul had added in few comments within the code, if you are still not able to understand it can you please explain which part of the code.